# Creating ViewModels using MEF in a MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, inversion-of-control, mef, ioc-container

This is going to be a bit lengthy, so hold on tight.

I have a project that uses `Caliburn.Micro` to implement MVVM pattern. For IoC, I am using MEF. All the ViewModels are marked with attribute `[Export(typeof(IScreen))]` . `IScreen` is defined in `Caliburn.Micro`.

In my `BootStrapper` file I have set up MEF like so:

```
private CompositionContainer container;

protected override void Configure()
{

    //Set up MEF

    container = new CompositionContainer(new AggregateCatalog``AssemblySource.Instance.Select``(x => new AssemblyCatalog(x)).OfType<ComposablePartCatalog>()));

    var batch = new CompositionBatch();

    batch.AddExportedValue<IWindowManager>(new WindowManager());

    batch.AddExportedValue<IEventAggregator>(new EventAggregator());

    batch.AddExportedValue(container);

    container.Compose(batch);

    //Other stuff
}
```

Now, I show the first ViewModel using

`protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e) => DisplayRootViewFor<ViewModels.Main.MainViewModel>();`

All that is fine and dandy. Now, the problem starts when I want to switch from one `ViewModel` to another.

An example of a ViewModel is :

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared), Export(typeof(IScreen))]
sealed class SampleViewModel: ScreenVMwithUoW<IAddItemUoW>
{
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public SampleViewModel(IAddItemUoW uow, IEventAggregator eventAggregator) : base(uow, eventAggregator)
    {

    }
    //bla bla bla
}
```

**Let's say I want to open `SampleViewModel` and close my `MainViewModel`. How do I do it using MEF?**

Here is what I am doing now:

```
[Export(typeof(IScreenFactory))]
class ScreenFactory : IScreenFactory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, ExportFactory<IScreen>> _screenDictionary { get;  set; }        
    private IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IScreen>> _screenfactoryCollection { get; set; }
    private ExportLifetimeContext<IScreen> _currentScreenLifeTimeCtx { get; set; }        

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ScreenFactory([ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)] IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IScreen>> screenList)
    {
        _screenfactoryCollection = screenList;
        _reportfactoryCollection = reportsList;            
    }

    public IScreen GetScreen(Type t)
    {
        if (_screenDictionary == null)
        {
            PopulateScreenDictionary(_screenfactoryCollection);
        }

        _currentScreenLifeTimeCtx = _screenDictionary[t].CreateExport();                
        return _currentScreenLifeTimeCtx.Value;
    }

    private void PopulateScreenDictionary(IEnumerable<ExportFactory<IScreen>> screenfactories)
    {
        _screenDictionary = screenfactories.ToDictionary(c => c.CreateExport().Value.GetType(), c => c);
    }

    public void DisposeCurrentScreenContext()
    {
        _currentScreenLifeTimeCtx?.Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        DisposeCurrentScreenContext();
    }
}
```

Whenever I need a new instance of a `ViewModel`, I just do:

```
DeactivateItem(ActiveItem, true);
_vmFactory.DisposeCurrentScreenContext();
ActivateItem(_vmFactory.GetScreen(NextViewModelName));
```

This CANNOT be the normal way to do so. Also, this also adds a huge hit in performance, especially the startup time of the application, when the number of `ViewModel`s increase to about 25-30.

I would also like to avoid the Service Locator Pattern, if possible. I am also open to using a proper IoC Container instead of `MEF`, but `MEF` allows me to add ViewModels with very little effort. Just adding the annotation `[Export(typeof(IScreen))]` does the job.

Comment: I've written something very similar to this; and yeah, navigation is a *huge* pain in the rear to get right (especially when you add in stuff like screens being able to cancel navigation!). I didn't notice a big perf hit though. I would say you are on the right track besides using MEF as a DI container (which it is not intended for).